# Is there a way to convert a graph into an object in Illustrator CC?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I've made a graph in Illustrator and I want to convert it to objects to make styling easier, I cannot seem to find anything that would do that.

How would I convert it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the graph and ungroup it.

Answer (score 0):

When working on the graph. make sure you click the check mark in the data window to close it. You will not be able to Ungroup the graph if the Data window is open.